# Lamp socket and wiring

Tags: lighting

I have 3 lamps with wattage restrictions of 30,70,100.  I would like to have wattage changed to 50,100,150. I have 3 other lamps that I could change from.  Do I have to change the wiring too or socket only.  They sure look like the same thing.  All are newer lamps. I just wasn’t sure if all needs to be changed.  Thanks

Comment: Do you have "3-way lamps" - i.e., turn switch once for 30, second time for 70, third time for 100? And that you want to use a 50/100/150 bulb? Or do you have 3 lamps, one of them has a 30 watt limit, one has a 70 watt limit, one has 100 watt limit. And in any case, just switch to LEDs and you'll get a lot more light (lumens) for a lot less power and not have any problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum wattage on lamps and light fixtures, even in today's era of CFL/LED bulbs being the norm, still refers to the socket's *heat* capacity when using incandescent light bulbs, since those are not efficient at all and give off significantly more heat than light, and because that's still the standard for wattage in the lighting industry. Even though it's more difficult to find incandescent bulbs now, they still exist and can still be purchased, so they're what fixtures are still rated against.

To that point, if you use CFL or LED bulbs, you should be fine with "50-100-150 watt **equivalent**" CFL/LED bulbs in the existing 30-70-100 socket. For example, a "60 watt equivalent" CFL bulb will use about 13 watts. A 60 watt LED bulb will use even less.

Comment: You mean the *fixture's* heat capacity.  It's not as simple as changing the socket; the insulation would also have to be enlarged, shrouds moved farther away, airflow improved, etc. as required.   GE makes an absolutely superb 50-150-100 (you read right) 3-way LED - it's rather expensive because it's not subsidized and because the build quality is a cut above the average LEDs most people buy.  The odd sequence is so the bulb will give 150 if placed in a 1-way socket.

Comment: @Harper I meant the socket's heat capacity, if the label is printed on the socket. If the label is printed on the fixture, then that's the fixture's heat capacity.